# JAVA GUI won't calculate the price

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I'm trying to make this application to calculate but it won't. Spend ages on it. I just want to calculate ones I press the button. I need it to display the correct price when clicking on the correct combo box. The prices have been set I think.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class retailsalescalcu extends JFrame {
    //create the objects
    JLabel department;
    JLabel number;
    JLabel name;
    JLabel price;
    JLabel discount;
    JLabel sale;
    JComboBox<String> dept;
    JTextField itemNum;
    JTextField itemName;
    JTextField itemPrice;
    JTextField itemDisc;
    JTextField salePrice;
    JButton calculate;
    JButton clear;

    public retailsalescalcu() {
        //set object variables
        super("Retail Sales Calculator");  //set window bar title
        setSize(300, 300);  //set window size
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //set window              close
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(7, 2);
        setLayout(grid);
        department = new JLabel("Department");
        dept = new JComboBox<String>();
            dept.addItem("Select");
            dept.addItem("Men's Clothing");
            dept.addItem("Women's Clothing");
            dept.addItem("Shoes");
            dept.addItem("Belts");
            dept.addItem("Electronics");
            dept.addItem("Hats");
            //add ItemListener - JTextField & ComboBox
            dept.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                    String str = (String)dept.getSelectedItem();
                    itemNum.setText(str);
                }  //end public void
            });  //end item listener
        number = new JLabel("Item Number");
        itemNum = new JTextField(10);
        name = new JLabel("Item Name");
        itemName = new JTextField(10);
        price = new JLabel("Original Price");
        itemPrice = new JTextField(10);
        discount = new JLabel("Discount");
        itemDisc = new JTextField(10);
        sale = new JLabel("Sale Price");
        salePrice = new JTextField(10);
        salePrice.setEditable(false);
        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");

        //add objects to JFrame
        add(department);
        add(dept);
        add(number);
        add(itemNum);
        add(name);
        add(itemName);
        add(price);
        add(itemPrice);
        add(discount);
        add(itemDisc);
        add(sale);
        add(salePrice);
        add(calculate);
        add(clear);    

        //add event listener to calculate sale price
        calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent retail) {
                String input1;
                String input2;
                double origPrice;
                double percOff;
                double clearance;   

                input1 = itemPrice.getText();
                input2 = itemDisc.getText();
                origPrice = Double.parseDouble(input1);
                percOff = Double.parseDouble(input2)/100;
                clearance = origPrice - (origPrice * percOff); 
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##");  
                df.format(clearance);                        
                salePrice.setText(df.format(clearance));                                         
                salePrice.setText(df.toString());  //output to JTextField    
            }
        });


        //add event listener to reset fields
        clear.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {  //JButton event if clicked
                dept.setSelectedIndex(0);  //Combo Box will be empty and can be reset
                itemNum.setText(null);  //Item Number will be empty and can be reset
                itemName.setText(null);  //Item Name will be empty and can be reset
                itemPrice.setText(null);  //Item Price will be empty and can be reset
                itemDisc.setText(null);  //Item Discount will be empty and can be reset
                salePrice.setText(null);  //Item SalePrice will be empty and can be reset
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }  //end public retailsalescalcu

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new retailsalescalcu();

    }  //end public static void

  }  //end public class retailsalescalcu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging you code i found that you should remove/comment line #100 from your code

From

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##");  
                        df.format(clearance);                        
                        salePrice.setText(df.format(clearance));                                         
                        salePrice.setText(df.toString());  //output to JTextField    
                        System.err.println(df.toString());
                    }
                });
```

to

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##");  
                        df.format(clearance);                        
                        salePrice.setText(df.format(clearance));                                         
                        //salePrice.setText(df.toString());  //output to JTextField    
                        System.err.println(df.toString());
                    }
                });
```

EDIT:

[image: I've attaching the o/p image for your satisfaction]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still doesn't work. Tried commenting out the line like you said. @Lalit Rao

Comment: I have attached the O/P image too. wat more do you want now?
It worked at my end

Comment: I'm sorry but I've tried it again and doesn't work. It could be my program, I'm using eclipse?

Comment: IDE has nothing to do with this. What exception you are getting? Better say wat text you are getting in Sale Price field?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at retailsalescalcu$2.actionPerformed(retailsalescalcu.java:87)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)

Comment: Exception says it all. Check your line number 87. I feel you have tangled the String name with each other

Comment: input1 = itemPrice.getText();
                        input2 = itemDisc.getText();
                        origPrice = Double.parseDouble(input1);
                        percOff = Double.parseDouble(input2)/100;
                        clearance = origPrice - (origPrice * percOff); 
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##");  
                        df.format(clearance);

Comment: salePrice.setText(df.format(clearance));                                         
                        //salePrice.setText(df.toString());  //output to JTextField    
                        System.err.println(df.toString());
                    }
                });

Comment: My code looks fine To be honest and I have implemented your advise. I'm sorry for wasting your time. But much appreciated.

Comment: Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHbSx2iVujE 
May be it would help u to understand the basics of creating and running Swing apps on Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
//salePrice.setText(df.toString());
```

Comment that out and you will see your price after clicking Calculate.  You are already setting `salesPrice` here:

```
salePrice.setText(df.format(clearance));
```

The `toString()` is not going to give you what you want.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, however I have already tried that and it still does not work. @whiskeyspider